# Why won't Difference subtract the geometry of this mesh?

Tags: modifiers, geometry

I am trying to subtract the big ring (highlighted in light orange) from the smaller ring (highlighted in dark orange) so that there is a slot down the middle of the smaller ring.

[image: rings]

I have tried every combination of Boolean modifiers, and they do not work. In the past, Difference sometimes worked to subtract geometry, but not always.

This is what happens when I apply a Difference modifier to the smaller ring and target the larger ring:

[image: failed difference]

As you can see, almost all of the ring is removed, except for a few tiny bits on the sides. I have no idea why this happens.

This is not the first time Difference has failed me, for seemingly-indecipherable reasons. Is there a way to force Difference to work logically, or, failing that, to subtract geometry another way?

[image]

Comment: it looks like you have quite a lot of self-intersection geometry on the upper and lower parts of the pitchring. if you view it using Z to see through the mesh you'll see some parts much darker than the rest.

Comment: probably difficult to see, but also there's a small shell / thickness going on in the pitchring, which seems also to cause self intersection.. -- zoom in real close

Answer (score 2):

[image]
Please consider

- Adding loop rings to the circular form.
- Select the middle faces.  Extrude -  No Movement Accept. Shrink Fatten. You may Shrink Fatten to create a cut out slot.

[image]